# Shorter way of saying "Uncertain of what was going on"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

> I saw a shadow fumbling inside my closet. [...] , I screamed.

I thought of the word *confused* but I think it doesn't have enough intensity. Is there a word/phrase that means *uncertain of what was going on*?

Comment: *(all) at sea,* idiom.

Comment: "Clueless" is the first word that comes to mind, though it doesn't quite fit the above context.  Probably either "spooked" or "alarmed", as suggested below (though neither is especially satisfying).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Bewildered* might do the trick:

> I saw a shadow fumbling inside my closet. Bewildered, I screamed.

Personally, I would use a word more synonymous to scared in this sentence, although I don't know what precedes it. *Alarmed* would most likely work as well.

The phrase *put on edge* implies intensity, and would fit in nicely.

> I saw a shadow fumbling inside my closet. Suddenly put on edge, I screamed.

Answer (score 6):

`Petrified` and `Horrified` would emphasize the fear factor more, while `Perplexed` and `Clueless` would emphasize the unawareness/uncertainty more.

Answer (score 4):

“Uncertain of what was going on” - [in the dark](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dark).

[Here](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/216394-the-phrase-in-the-dark-as-i-m-sure-you-know) is a nice quote from Lemony Snicket's 'The End'.

So here is a little pun:

I saw a shadow fumbling inside my closet. Being in the dark, I screamed.

Answer (score 3):

Although it may not be the best fit for "uncertain of what was going on," I think *startled* fits perfectly within the context of the sentence you include in your question:

**[startle](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/startle):** to do something unexpected that surprises and sometimes worries a person or animal.

> I saw a shadow fumbling inside my closet.  Startled, I screamed.

Answer (score 2):

Consider *[befuddled](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/befuddled)*

> confused, muddled, addled, bewildered, disoriented, fazed, perplexed, dazed, dizzy, stupefied, groggy, muzzy, foggy, fuddled, fuzzy, dopey, woozy, befogged, mixed up

*Collins*

Also

> - muddled
> - addled
> - bewildered
> - disoriented
> - dazed
> - stupefied

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps "spooked [out]", "unnerved", or "freaked [out]"?

> **spook**: frighten; unnerve: they spooked a couple of grizzly bears.
>
> [ no obj. ] (especially of an animal) take fright suddenly: he'll spook if we make any noise.
>
> **unnerve**: make (someone) lose courage or confidence: the bleakness of his gaze unnerved her | (as adj. unnerving) : an unnerving experience.
>
> **freak**: informal behave or cause to behave in a wild and irrational way, typically because of the effects of extreme emotion, mental illness, or drugs: [ no obj. ] : I could have freaked out and started smashing the place up | [ with obj. ] : he freaks guest stars out on show day.

Answer (score 1):

Unbeknownst! Unbeknownst to me, they had already left.. Works perfectly.

Comment: I don't see how this fits into the questioner's example phrase... "I saw a shadow fumbling inside my closet. _Unbeknownst_, I screamed."